# How do I create the image using standard draw?

Tags: java

Here is the picture I am trying to draw that using the StdDraw library.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Ag19EHN.png]

So far I have:

```
public class Triangles { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        StdDraw.setXscale(0, N);
        StdDraw.setYscale(0, N);


        for (double i = 0; i < N + 1; i++) {
            for (double j = 0; j < N + 1; j++) {
                if ((i + j) % 2 != 0) 
                    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
                else                  
                    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.RED);
                StdDraw.line(0,j,N,j);
                StdDraw.line(0,i,i,0);
            }
        }
        StdDraw.show();
    }
}
```

To run this program you need to create `StdDraw.java` and save it in the same directory as my above code, with the source code for StdDraw found [here](https://repl.it/Be1Z)

I understand that the code above would only draw lines for me. How would I draw the triangles using filledPolygon? It appears to need a list of doubles but i'm not sure how to do that.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: You did not post an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You cannot expect people to go through the link you posted to find out what the code actually is. Edit your post and add a minimal, verifiable and executable example that clearly demonstrates the problem you have.

Comment: @TT. I added the link because running the code requires another .java file to be in the same directory, that is all.